# Verifying Ubuntu on Windows 7 (total newbie)

Tags: windows-7, gnupg

Friends, I would like to specify my question a little bit, cause a lot of you give me suggestions that are already written in this page  www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify

What confused me is that tip in the 2nd step, where it says :

> Tip: On non-Linux systems, you might need to download the GPG tools for this next step. To check if you have the GPG tools installed, run the command gpg --version or gpg2 --version.

Now, it's not written WHERE do I have to write these commands. At the beginning in that page it says "These instructions assume basic knowledge of the command line", so I assumed I needed to open a "Command prompt" program for that, is it right ? 
I don't understand why isn't it mentioned in that tip, it is really confusing for a newbie like me. And the results that I get when writing these commands in the "Command prompt" are confusing as well. But knowing that the gnuPG has never ever been installed on my laptop I don't expect too much more. 
But still it would be good if it was written in that tip what you should see if it's not installed AND that from Windows OS you have to open a Command prompt program to write these commands in.

**Previous question**

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I downloaded the iso image and now I want to verify it. I currently have Windows 7 as OS on my computer.

In this page www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify in the 2nd step there is this tip that says:

> Tip: On non-Linux systems, you might need to download the GPG tools for this next step. To check if you have the GPG tools installed, run the command gpg --version or gpg2 --version.

Now as I understand I need to write `gpg --version` when I open the command promt program is that right?
I tried and it is unrecognized. But it's okay because I have never ever installed it on my laptop. The thing I worry a bit is am I doing it right? Do I need to use command prompt program for this?

[image: my command prompt image (click to see)]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows MD5SUM on Windows
Windows does not come with md5sum. You must download one from another location, preferably one that you trust. There are command line utilities (md5sum.exe) that work similarly to the Unix utility; one public domain version with source is available from Fourmilab,

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. What I really really want to know is do I have to use "command prompt" program to write these commands which are mentioned in this sentence "To check if you have the GPG tools installed, run the command gpg --version or gpg2 --version."   This sentence is from ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify

Comment: yes, you need to run those commands at the prompt

Comment: The command you posted works just great in Ubuntu's terminal. I would doubt it works the same in Windows. Use the howto MD5sum link above in Windows.

Comment: Strange. 

Maybe in that Tip posted above, in the first sentence, an author talks about non-linux systems, but in the second sentence he then talks about linux systems. That's the only way I can explain it. 
A bit confusing I would say.

Answer (score 2):

[CertUtil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) (certutil.exe) is a preinstalled Windows command-line program that can be used to generate hash checksums:

```
certUtil -hashfile pathToFileToCheck [HashAlgorithm]
```

certutil.exe ships with Windows 7 and later. CertUtil supports MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 and SHA512 hash algorithms.

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea. I’ll just go ahead and remove my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `gpg` installed. You can install it for windows using this link: https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html

Then you can download the ISO and checksum over at (Be sure to download a file that ends with .gpg) http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

And run cmd, cd into your Downloads directory (Or where your ISO and checksum has been saved) and run these commands:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FBB75451
```

and I also had to run `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EFE21092`

Incase this changes, if you get an error reading:

> gpg: Signature made 08/05/16 01:13:26 West-Europa (zomertijd) using DSA key ID FBB75451
>   gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

Use `gpg --keyserver hpk://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FBB75451`

```
gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

That checks the checksum with the ISO. (And it might take a while)

EDIT - Added information from @grooveplex
You might see a warning `'This key is not certified with a trusted signature!'.` This warning means that there is no path in the Web of Trust between this key and you. The warning is harmless as long as you retrieved the key from a trusted source. If GPG fails and reports 'BAD signature', do not use the ISO.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I will use this information you have posted and it will be helpful for me. Will check it this week.

Comment: You might see a warning `'This key is not certified with a trusted signature!'`. This warning means that there is no path in the Web of Trust between this key and you. The warning is harmless as long as you retrieved the key from a trusted source. If GPG fails and reports 'BAD signature',  _do not use the ISO_.

Comment: Hello @grooveplex, 

So I began to apply your knowledge and everything went fine but on the last step I encountered a problem. When I type the last command 

> gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 

I get this message 

> gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg' : No such file or directory
> gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory

But I have all files in one folder so why do I get these messages, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [This answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/898377/366962)

[**CertUtil**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) comes with Windows and can be used to generate the checksum of a file:

```
certUtil -hashfile pathToFileToCheck [HashAlgorithm]
```

The HashAlgorithm choicesare: MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512. If no algorithm is selected CertUtil defaults to SHA1

So for example, the following generates an MD5 checksum for the file 
`C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img`:

```
  CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5
```

The output of this has extraneous lines describing which algorithm is used, the filename and whether the command was successful. To match the output of the checksum utilities in Ubuntu, such as `md5sum` use PowerShell to format the output:

```
$(CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5)[1] -replace " ",""
```

Comment: As promised!  **;-)**